# "Initializer is not a compile time constant" error works in .mm?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I'm puzzled by a situation I'm observing and would love some insight. First, I'm using Xcode 5, with LLVM 5 compiler options set to defaults.

I have a line in a .m file such as:

```
static NSArray * const kSchemaVersions = @[@"1"];
```

And, as expected, I see a compiler error saying `Initializer element is not a compile-time constant.`

*However*, if I place this same line in a `.mm` (Objective C++) file, the compiler does not complain.

I completely understand why it shouldn't work, but I'm baffled as to why it appears to.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mentioned, in C and Objective-C static variables can only be initialised with compile-time constants. In C++ (and therefore Objective-C++) on the other hand, static variables are assigned at run time, before `main` runs.

For more details have a look at Eli Bendersky's [Non-constant global initialization in C and C++](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/03/08/non-constant-global-initialization-in-c-and-c/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and link to Eli's blog. The clarity for me came from this passage: "In C++ much more is being determined at runtime before the user’s main function runs. This is in order to allow proper construction of global and static objects (C++ objects may have user-defined constructors, which isn’t true for C)."

Comment: It should be mentioned, that you are talking about static fields of a class. If we consider static variables inside functions, they will be initialized, when the function is first called, not before `main` runs.