# static NSObject in method

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I want to use static NSObject like NSArray in some methods like this:

```
- (void)func
{
    static NSArray *localStatic = @[@1,@2];
}
```

I know it won't compile when objective-c, but when I change the file to x.mm to use objective-c++, it works.
Can anybody explain why?

Thanks

Comment: Search on the error you get and you will find plenty of discussions on the problem and its solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Initializer is not a compile time constant" error works in .mm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870520/initializer-is-not-a-compile-time-constant-error-works-in-mm) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304740/initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant-why

Comment: Which error do you get?