# How to create a constant with a custom type (complex) object

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants

It is not question on something trivial like creating a constant string or a number but to have a constant of custom type or complex object e.g.

```
//.h
extern CSResourceName* const RESOURCE_COURSE_WRAPPER;

//.m
CSResourceName* const RESOURCE_COURSE_WRAPPER = [CSResourceName 
                                          resourceNameWithName:@"wrapper" 
                                                     Extension:@"html"];
                    //here I've
                    //tried also differently like 
                    //[[CSResourceName new] initWithName:Extension:]
```

but compiler returns "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant".

Is there a way to have a constant with an object like here (custom)? From other questions (similar by error message) I know that it will not allow for classes to be constants. How in objective-c you can have a constant values of complex objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304740/initializer-element-is-not-a-compile-time-constant-why)

Comment: really? duplicate? I've seen this question before asking and I'm sure it is not the same and none of proposed solutions applies.

Comment: Your const is a CSResourceName* type.  Just a pointer.  And you're asking the compiler to set that pointer value to... the result of a method.  Before any code executes.  Maybe you could statically allocate a chunk of space for your const pointer to point to, but you'd still need to fill it by executing code.  @Desdenova is right.  Your question is a dupe.  You can do this in ObjC++ but not C.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870520/initializer-is-not-a-compile-time-constant-error-works-in-mm

Comment: the real answer is to give resolution to the custom object as constant not stating that this is a pointer, just a pointer and so help me pointer...